# Microsoft Graph API Application Logo

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

With the May 2017 beta update, retrieve the application logo through the GRAPH API changed from mainLogo to Logo. When tested through the Graph Explorer with the new API, it's now given an error message as follows, tried the logoUrl property, it also failed.

API Call
`https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/applications/[ApplicationID]/logo`

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "Request_UnsupportedQuery",
        "message": "This property logo cannot be read. Please use the logoUrl property.",
        "innerError": {
            "request-id": "623806c0-6255-4b7d-bce1-d1cb7a982e6c",
            "date": "2017-06-09T20:21:37"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is your question, do you want to help with the URL, or something else?

Comment: The new API for retrieving the application logo does not work and given the post error. How do I retrieve the application logo through Graph API

Answer (score 1):

logoUrl is under info, for example `https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/applications/[ApplicationID]/info/logoUrl`